# UI5 - how to dynamically bind data to a Select in Table, depending on another combobox?

Tags: sapui5

I have a classic situation - a table with two comboboxes (or, to be exact, sap.m.Select controls) and after select in the first one, I would like to have the values in the second one updated. This is my model, basically, the first combobox should contain the list of available states and once some is selected, the second sap.m.Select control should be populated by relevant cities

```
{
 countries: [
 { country: 'France', cities: ['Paris', 'Marseille', 'Lyon']},
 { country: 'Germany', cities: ['Berlin', 'Bonn']}
]
}
```

The problem is that I dont know how to do it. I am able to get the id of the updated row using something like this.

```
onCountryChange: function (oEvent) {
    const selectedItem = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem");
    var path = selectedItem.getBindingContext().getPath();
    bindComboBox(path); // this should rebind the data, but not written yet
}
```

I know now I should rebind the data in the correct combobox, however, I don't know how to affect only that single combobox on the correct row and how to update it. Could someone advise me how to do it? The whole table is defined in the .xml view, can I do it also with a formatter or inline expression or is this scenario too difficult for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bindAggregation method (from the ManagedObject) class to rebind the combo boxes' items.

```
onCountryChange: function (oEvent) {
    const selectedItem = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem");
    var path = selectedItem.getBindingContext().getPath();

    this.byId("combo2").bindAggregation("items", {
        path: path + "/cities",
        template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
            key: "{}",
            text: "{}"
        })
    });
}
```

Note: Replacing "combo2" with the id of your 2nd combo box/select control.

Edit: To get the correct combo box (assuming you have multiple created on a table, use the ID of the first combo box (`oEvent.getSource().getId()`) to generate the ID of the 2nd combo box. Without knowing more of the structure of the table (and how it's created) I can't offer more.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advice. I used your code, getting combobox is not a problem since its declared statically in the xml file. However, it does nothing, probably because I didnt place the question well enough - I am using sap.m.Select controls which have no method bindAggregation (and if I use method bindItems instead, I get the error "Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element "). Do you know how to bind those items dynamically to sap.m.Select control? Thanks a million

Comment: bindItems(args) is simply bindAggregation("items", args) so the above properties object should also work. The error refers to an inability to find out how to layout each item in the aggregation. You need to supply either a template (an item to copy to each row) or a factory function, that is called with the context, to generate a row.

Comment: Thank you, seems the code above is working after all - I didnt retrieve the second combobox correctly. Therefore, the question is answered. Now I only need to find out how to retrieve the id of that second control - I have the id of the Select control and also parsed the row clicked. If there is some fast way to get it, I would be very grateful, if not, I will try to google a bit more...

Comment: Great news! If setting the ID's doesn't work, you could also use the first combo boxes' getParent method and walk up the rendering tree to then find the other combo box. Good luck!

Comment: No need, got an id through "this.byId('table').getRows()[row].getCells()[1];" Thanks again!